# iphone mkannotation: warning on left callout after map has loaded

Tags: objective-c, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I have a MKMapview loading with maybe 5 annotations (right now). It loads fine, with the annotations as well. Each annotation contains the correct left and right callout. However after a while (maybe 2 minutes) i often get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash, on the left callout of an annotation...

```
- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)thisMapView 
         viewForAnnotation:(MapAnnotations *)annotation
{
static NSString *MapIdentifier = @"MapIdentifier";

UIImageView *myImageView;
MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[thisMapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:MapIdentifier];

if(annotationView == nil)
{   
    NSString * id = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (annotation).tag];
    NSString * postPhoto = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"id=%@",id];
    NSString * hostStrPhoto = @"http://domain.com/get_image.php?";
    hostStrPhoto = [hostStrPhoto stringByAppendingString:postPhoto];

    NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:hostStrPhoto]];

    myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithData: imgData]];

    myImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,31,31); 

    annotationView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:MapIdentifier] autorelease];

}

annotationView.animatesDrop=TRUE;


annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
annotationView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = myImageView; //<--where I am getting the error, after all the annotations have loaded.
annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];

return annotationView;

[myImageView autorelease];
```

}

I am thinking maybe my app is still trying to load annotations, but I can't figure out why. As well i am getting some memory warnings when the map is loaded, so perhaps I am not releasing some objects the way i should be, i'm still kind of new to how the memory management works, so any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you end up re-using an annotation view, myImageView isn't created, yet you're releasing it. Set myImageView to nil at the top.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)thisMapView viewForAnnotation:(MapAnnotations *)annotation {
    static NSString *MapIdentifier = @"MapIdentifier";

    UIImageView *myImageView = nil;
    MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[thisMapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:MapIdentifier];

    if(annotationView == nil) {   
        NSString * id = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (annotation).tag];
        NSString * postPhoto = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"id=%@",id];
        NSString * hostStrPhoto = @"http://domain.com/get_image.php?";
        hostStrPhoto = [hostStrPhoto stringByAppendingString:postPhoto];

        NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:hostStrPhoto]];

        myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithData: imgData]];

        myImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,31,31); 

        annotationView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:MapIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    annotationView.animatesDrop=TRUE;
    annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
    annotationView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = myImageView; //<--where I am getting the     error, after all the annotations have loaded.
    annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton     buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];

    return annotationView;

    [myImageView release]; 
}
```